# TopoJSON ‹‹properties›› field, how to get values with d3.js?

Tags: d3.js, topojson

I have TopoJSON file, it looks like this:

`{"type":"Topology","transform":{"scale":[0.03600360003702599,0.0040674580654071245],"translate":[-179.9999967702229,41.18684289776669],"objects":{"country":{"type":"GeometryCollection","geometries":[{"type":"Polygon","arcs":[[0]],"properties":{"AREA":29809500,"PERIMETER":21822.4,"region":"XYZ"}},…`

I want to use values of properties ("AREA","PERIMETER","region") in my d3.js code. I made attempt to get some values, but it didn't work:

```
d3.json("map_topo.json", function(error, map) {
svg.append("path")
.datum(topojson.object(map, map.objects.country).geometries)
.attr("d", path)
.style("fill", function(d) {
if (d.properties.region == "XYZ")
 {return "red"}
else {return "gray"}
})
```

What I'm doing wrong?

*UPD*: issue was solved with help of @ChrisWilson, problem was in appending **one** path, instead of selecting **ALL** paths. Working code (for topojson.v0.js):

```
d3.json("map_topo.json", function(error, map) {
svg.selectAll("path")
.data(topojson.object(map, map.objects.country).geometries)
.enter().append("path")
.attr("d", path)
.style("fill", function(d) {
if (d.properties.region == "XYZ")
{return "red"}
else {return "gray"}
});
```

For topojson.v1.js use `topojson.feature` method (look comments below).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You appear to be making one large map, not a series of `path` objects representing countries. Try this:

```
d3.json("map_topo.json", function(error, map) {
    svg.selectAll("path")
       .data(topojson.feature(us, us.objects.counties).features)
       .enter()
       .append("path")
       .attr("d", path)
       .style("fill", function(d) {
           if (d.properties.region == "XYZ")
               {return "red"}
           else {return "gray"}
       });
```

I can't be sure this will work without seeing the TopoJSON file, but basically you need a `topojson` method that will produce an array.

See the [choropleth map example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4060606) for a good example: The states are mapped as one path with `.mesh()` while the counties are mapped as individual objects like the code above.

Comment: Your code returns `TypeError: topojson.feature is not a function`.

Comment: But you right about one large map it's about svg.selectAll("path"). I tried this and it works! (P.S. can't cope with code listing in comments, 4 spaces indent doesn't work, just unreadable code mess =( )

Comment: Yeah, but i just don't know how to make it properly here.

Comment: You need to upgrade to the v1 release of the TopoJSON client library ([topojson.v1.js](http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.js) or [topojson.v1.min.js](http://d3js.org/topojson.v1.min.js)). The v1 release replaced `topojson.object` with `topojson.feature`; the behavior is similar, but the new `topojson.feature` method returns a Feature or FeatureCollection (rather than a Geometry or GeometryCollection) for better compatibility with GeoJSON.