# topojson.object in topojson V1

Tags: d3.js, geojson, topojson

I am having a lot of fun playing with topojson, but it looks like topojson.object is undefined in V1 of topojson, where it was supported in V0.  Can someone explain how I might work around this issue?  I am trying to draw distinct path elements for each polygon in an input file formatted as topojson.  the code is:

```
d3.json("maTopo.json", function(error, ma) {
    svg.selectAll(".subunit")
      .data(topojson.object(ma, ma.objects.ma).geometries)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return "subunit " + d.id; })
      .attr("d", path);
});
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17404239/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `topojson.feature` instead.

```
d3.json("maTopo.json", function(error, ma) {
  svg.selectAll(".subunit")
      .data(topojson.feature(ma, ma.objects.ma).features)
    .enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", function(d) { return "subunit " + d.id; })
      .attr("d", path);
});
```

A detailed example can be found here: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/map/

Answer (score 4):

> The v1 release replaced topojson.object with topojson.feature; the behavior is similar, but the new topojson.feature method returns a Feature or FeatureCollection (rather than a Geometry or GeometryCollection) for better compatibility with GeoJSON.

@mbostock's words from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16305419/topojson-properties-field-how-to-get-values-with-d3-js). So change just one string in your code to this:`.data(topojson.feature(ma, ma.objects.ma).features)`. And I guess you also should regenerate your TopoJSON file with v1 from GeoJSON.