# Topojson: list of differences between v0 and v1?

Tags: json, dictionary, gis, topojson

I'am merging code, the code relying on v0 breaks on v1.

**What are the syntaxes changes between topojson.v0.min.js and topojson.v1.min.js?***

--

**List of suspect syntaxes:**

- V0 > V1
- .object > .feature
- .geometries > .features (in some cases or always?)
- *.coordinates > *.geometry.coordinates
- others ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The 1.0.0 major release (see [release notes](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/releases/v1.0.0)) replaced the topojson.object function with topojson.feature for better GeoJSON compatibility.

In previous versions of TopoJSON, topojson.object returned a geometry object (which may be a geometry collection), consistent with how the geometry object is represented inside the TopoJSON [Topology](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/Specification). However, unlike GeoJSON geometries, TopoJSON geometries are more like features, and could have an id and properties; likewise, null geometries were represented as a null type.

As of version 1.0.0, [topojson.feature](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/wiki/API-Reference#wiki-feature) replaces topojson.object, returning a Feature or a FeatureCollection instead, consistent with how the geometry was originally represented in the GeoJSON, prior to conversion to TopoJSON. (As in GeoJSON, null geometries are represented as features with a null geometry object.) As discussed in [#37](https://github.com/mbostock/topojson/issues/37), this offers greater compatibility with the [GeoJSON specification](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html) and libraries that deal with GeoJSON.

To upgrade your code, you can replace topojson.object with topojson.feature. However, **code that assumed that topojson.object returned a geometry must be changed to handle the feature (or feature collection)** now returned by topojson.feature. For example, prior to 1.0, if you said:

```
svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(topojson.object(topology, topology.objects.states).geometries)
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", path);
```

In 1.0 and later, the corresponding code is:

```
svg.selectAll("path")
    .data(topojson.feature(topology, topology.objects.states).features)
  .enter().append("path")
    .attr("d", path);
```

Likewise, if you were iterating over an array of point geometries, prior to 1.0, you might have said:

```
topojson.object(topology, topology.objects.points).geometries.forEach(function(point) {
  console.log("x, y", point.coordinates[0], point.coordinates[1]);
});
```

In 1.0 and later, the corresponding code is:

```
topojson.feature(topology, topology.objects.points).features.forEach(function(point) {
  console.log("x, y", point.geometry.coordinates[0], point.geometry.coordinates[1]);
});
```

Comment: @RobinKraft: if you find some pairs to replace, please add them to the list inside the question.