# Topojson v.0 to v.1 migration difficulties

Tags: topojson

I used recommendations by Mike Bostock on [Topojson: list of differences between v0 and v1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17404239/) to migrate my code from v0 to v1.

- [Topojson_v0](https://codio.io/hugolpz/D3-map/Topojson%20v0.html) -- Working.
- [Topojson_v1](https://codio.io/hugolpz/D3-map/Topojson%20v1.html) -- Labels of points are shut down.

No other changes made.

My data is [the same final_adms_France.json file](https://codio.io/hugolpz/D3-map/data/adm/final_adms_France.json).

**What is the issue ? How to make it work ?**

---

**Comment:** Seems I got an issue with :

```
 .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + projection(d.coordinates) + ")"; })
```

out of :

```
// Positioning: place-label
    svg.selectAll(".place-label")
        .data(topojson.object(fra, fra.objects.places).geometries)
      .enter().append("text")
        .attr("class", "place-label")
        .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + projection(d.coordinates) + ")"; })
        .attr("dy", ".35em")
        .text(function(d) { if (d.properties.name!=="Paris"&&d.properties.name!=="Bremen"){return d.properties.name;} })
        .attr("x", function(d) { return d.coordinates[0] > -1 ? 6 : -6; })
        .style("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.coordinates[0] > -1 ? "start" : "end"; });
```

Comment: Have you tried using `d.geometry.coordinates`?

Comment: Works. I tried `d.geometires.coordinates` previously. Thanks Alex. I've been on this for a while. (note: repost in the answer field so I +1 and validate)

Comment: so `d` in my sample behave like `point` in Bostock's sample. Not easy for newbies!

Comment: Exactly, you have to treat objects as features and access their property paths accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `d.geometry.coordinates` instead of `d.coordinates`.